# avoid screen getting pushed up into status bar when keyboard is open

Tags: keyboard, react-native, statusbar

On opening the keyboard, and on pressing the next button from the keyboard, the screen gets pushed up into the status bar, making the contents of the statusbar and the screen to **overlap in react native android**. I am using *react-native version 0.59.2* and *react-native-router-flux version 0.4.6*

1. I have tried using keyboard avoiding view but no success.
2. I have also tried setting  **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"**, but using it pushes my tab bar over the keyboard.
3. Making the combination of  **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"**, however does not pushes the screen above the status bar, but does make my screen scroll automatically, thus user has to scroll manually.

***StatusBar Component***

```
<StatusBar translucent={true} hidden={false} backgroundColor={'rgba(0,0,0,0.0)'} barStyle={"light-content"}/>
```

This is how I am using it in the class.

```
<View style={{flex:1}>
       <StatusBar/>
       <Header/>
       <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <TextInput/> //here i have multiple textinput fields
       </ScrollView>
   </View>
```

Expected result should be "the screen should go beneath the statusbar and not over it."

Comment: any update on this?